# How to find ID of the closest upper element with specific class name?

Tags: jquery, css-selectors

HTML Code:

```
<div id="1" class="master"></div>
<div id="2" class="slave"></div>
<div id="3" class="slave"></div>

<div id="4" class="master"></div>
<div id="5" class="slave"></div>
<div id="6" class="slave"></div>
```

let's say, we use $('div').click() to make these DIV elements clickable:

```
$('div').click(function() {
    var el = $(this);
    var master_id = ???;
    alert(master_id);
});
```

Then, clicking on DIV elements with class "slave" we need to alert the ID of the closest upper DIV element with class "master", so, if we click on DIV#5 or DIV#6, alerts = "4" (DIV#4), if DIV#2 or DIV#3 - alerts = "1" (DIV#1).
But how to do that? ;)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**Updated:**

```
$('div').click(function() {
    var el = $(this);
    var master_id = el.prevAll('.master').attr('id');
    alert(master_id);
});
```

**Edit:**
you can also use filters so that when you click a div with calss 'master' it will not fire the event:

```
$('div').click(function(e) {
    var el =$(this);
    if (!el.is('.master')){
        var master_id = el.prevAll(".master").attr('id');
    alert(master_id);
    }
```

Comment: closest traverses parents, it won't find a sibling element as the OP is looking to do.

Comment: Thanks for your reply.
Unfortunately, your implemention alerts "undefined" when clicking on "slave" DIV elements, and its ID when clicking of "master" DIV elements.

Comment: 2 great_llama, do you know the solution?

Answer (score 0):

I first thought [prev](http://docs.jquery.com/Traversing/prev#expr) would do, but after some testing I noticed it won't work on a `slave` not placed directly after another `slave`. Grabbing the first match from [prevAll](http://docs.jquery.com/Traversing/prevAll#expr) worked perfectly.

Demo: http://jsbin.com/ulipi

```
$('.slave').click(function() {
    var el = $(this);
    var master_id = $(el.prevAll('.master').get(0)).attr('id');
    alert(master_id);
});
```